# Color checker for comparing print to screen output

Tags: color, print-design

I want to print a color checker to have a set of colors to compare the output from the printer with what I see on the screen. Does anybody have a standard color checker? I can also google one, but apart from something that looks like a nice set of colors I don't really know what's important here...

Comment: What do you mean, like a Pantone scale?

Comment: I was thinking something like these: https://news.artnet.com/art-world/gerhard-richter-color-charts-turn-50-322319 It would be useful if I want to check a certain color in an image i.e. beige or a red brown and compare it to the color checker too predict the results from the printer.

Comment: what exactly do you want that a Pantone scale can't provide?

Comment: Well I think I'm missing something here (like I said, maybe it's a stupid question)... I work with photos, so I can't take i.e. Pantone 199 out of a color picker. In my opinion a color checker that I have digitally (in Photoshop) but also on print (print sample from the printer) could be useful to check & compare colors before sending the final image to the printer. So that's why I was looking for a good system/color scale/color picker/...

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution will not work for you to compare before sending a document off to a commercial printer.  For that, I think you really need a Pantone swatch kit.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're looking for this for Photographic accuracy than what you probably want is to look at the X-Rite product lineup of ColorChecker Targets. You'll then also want to look into theirs or others Monitor and Printer Calibration. This will provide you much more consistent results than attempting to print your own.

ColorChecker Targets:

[image]

Printer Calibration:

[image]

[i1Photo Pro 2 Professional Color Management](http://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?id=1913&catid=109) for Photographers would be a complete kit but you might be better served looking at individual product options. There are also plenty of competitors of varying quality to x-rite.

---

For more on the subject you may want to visit the Photography Stack Exchange:

- [Photo.SE: Color Calibration](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=color%20calibration)
- [Photo.SE: ColorChecker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=colorchecker)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing about a year ago, I stumbled across something in my printer that has worked well for me. Try digging into the utilities available with your printer--I found that both the printers in our office have the ability to print out a color sample sheet.  My HP printer can print out a list of CMYK and/or RGB colors: 
[image]

And the Kyocera printer has a color chart that is actually matched to Pantone colors:[image]

The option to print the page is available in the utilities of my HP printer:

[image]

But I had to dig fairly deeply into the information that we received with the Kyocera to find the page there (it was on a thumb drive that they provided us when we first leased the printer).

I would go to the website for your particular printer and do some searching for a color sampler, or something like it, and see if you can find something similar for your particular printer model.

**EDITED TO ADD:** 
By the way, this is a great way to find out what colors are reproduced well on your specific printer.  Our Kyocera is really awful with blues--about 40% of the blue hues look like the same washed out blue jeans color.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this one? An oldie but a goodie!

For doing simple calibration of your monitor to a printer it works pretty well. For actual colour calibration of your monitors other answers already provided here will give you the best solution.

[image: ole no moire]